# Django/MySQl how to fix Database returned an invalid datetime value. Are time zone definitions for your database installed?

Tags: python, mysql, django, phpmyadmin, cpanel

**What Happened**

After moving my `Django` app - which was working as expected - from a VPS to shared hosting with `Cpanel` I changed Database from `PostgresSQL` to `MySQL`, whenever I open an object that has `created_at` field which is a `Datetime Field` I Get this error.

**Error**

```
Database returned an invalid datetime value. Are time zone definitions for your database installed?
```

**What I've tried**

After some searching, I've found out that it can be fixed by running this  command in `terminal`

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

That command should populate the Timezone tables in my database.

**The Problem**

I can't run the comment mentioned above as am using `Cpanel` shared hosting and am very limited on my choices and commands that I can run using `terminal`. so I tried to run it I got this error

[image]

**What I need**

I think the solution now is to find a way to populate the timezone tables on the `Mysql` database using only `PhpMyAdmin` and not using the `terminal`

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly this error is addressed in [Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#troubleshooting),

> I get an error “Are time zone definitions for your database installed?”
>
> If you are using MySQL, see the [Time zone definitions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/databases/#mysql-time-zone-definitions) section of the MySQL notes for instructions on loading time zone definitions.

once we check inside the Time zone definitions, we read

> If you plan on using Django’s [timezone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/timezones/) support, use [mysql_tzinfo_to_sql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html) to load time zone tables into the MySQL database. This needs to be done just once for your MySQL server, not per database.

Knowing that OP can run that, I'd get in touch with the hosting provider to do that.

Comment: I agree; contacting your host's support is probably best in your shared hosting situation, but for others who are responsible for managing their own server but don't have command line access:

You can probably fire up any local Linux installation, run `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo > timezonefile.sql`, then import 'timezonefile.sql' through phpmyAdmin.